Selenium doesn't return all cookie values of the page
import logging
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)



try:
    # Set Chrome options to headless
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

    # Initialize the Chrome driver
    logger.info("Initializing Chrome WebDriver")
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

    if driver is None:
        raise Exception("Failed to initialize WebDriver")

    logger.info("Navigating to the webpage")
    driver.get("https://www.nayaraenergy.com/petrol-pump-near-me")

    # Ensure the page is fully loaded
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # Wait for up to 10 seconds for the elements to appear

    # Get the cookies
    logger.info("Retrieving cookies")
    cookies = driver.get_cookies()

    session_data = {}
    # Print the cookies
    for cookie in cookies:
        print(cookie)
        data = {
            cookie['name']: cookie['value']
        }
        session_data.update(data)
    print(session_data)
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f"An error occurred: {e}", exc_info=True)

finally:
    if driver is not None:
        logger.info("Closing the driver")
        driver.quit()

I am trying to get the cookie information of the page -
The above code works to a certain extent, but fails to output all the cookie values
the whole data of the cookie is :

_fbp=fb.1.1722150867062.324436436556492225; _**hjSessionUser_3422175=some_data;**_gid=GA1.2.353944606.1722412003;**_hjSession_3422175=some_data**;
_ga_6EDN8NZ3RQ=GS1.1.1722433679.6.0.1722433679.60.0.0; _ga_5WCBPP0WF1=GS1.1.1722433679.7.0.1722433679.0.0.0; _ga=GA1.2.1174399862.1722150866; _gat_gtag_UA_142048367_1=1; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlA0MWIxZHR1WXZvaHBFZHhtU3E2dVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoieDV3ZVZRdEpxRWRreUVrWEZQQ0lUWEQ3dGRWUnhLa3JidjR5eGxIc3BVbGl3REZYWmN1SDdIb0dVdTZyN1lDTSIsIm1hYyI6IjgwNmExMTE4MDFkMTkyZGVlYmZkMzVlYjMyYTNhMzg0ODNiNDdmMjdiZTFkNmRlOTYxYzAxMWUwN2Q4YzgwNzAifQ%3D%3D;
laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjVoYkNuOG5hbXF3bVZZd0VGanpHNmc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNm8yaGVXdWllbTQxWGJ1T3p5QkQ4Tmc1QXlhT2E2UG1KOUgyQnF5dkFkVHV4QWZobklGOEF1dG5weGNBNUdZdiIsIm1hYyI6IjljOWQ3MGI4MjgyM2Q1MDZiM2JjN2M1OTcxZWIxMDk0MzgyMTc3MTQ3ZDg1ODExNDdmY2EwN2JkMjJmNmY2Y2YifQ%3D%3D

This session has already expired, so no point trying the tokens
but when i use the get_cookies() function, it doesn't outputs the hjSessionUser_3422175 and hjSession_3422175
Chatgpt was of no use, I tried finding the get_cookie function in their github repo to understand the workings, but can't seem to find it, guess it's built in in the webdriver itself.

Sometimes some of the cookies load after some time or condition. Can you try waiting more before reading cookies?

Nope, not working, i tried with 20 sec sleep, still nothing.

are you trying to replicate the post request?

you won't be able to get HTTPOnly cookies.  You'd need to intercept the response (maybe try new Bidi protocol).  Though even that might be problematic without using another application like WireShark.  Set-Cookie responses are always first (they go straight to the browser).  Then a separate response for content.
